# Uploading image to ASP.NET Core app using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, image-uploading

I am new to jQuery and AJAX and I am trying to upload image to my server using it. I have a simple html page

```
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input id="profilePic" name="picture" type="file" size="1" onchange="uploadFile('profilePic');" />
</form>
```

where script file is

```
function uploadFile(inputId) {
var fileUpload = $("#" +inputId).get(0);
var files = fileUpload.files;
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append(files[0].name, files[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: '/Image/File',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (result) {
    }
});
```

In my controller named ImageController I have a POST method named File which takes zero arguments:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult File()
{
    var file = Request.Form.Files[0];

    if (file != null)
    {
        //work
    }

    return null;
}
```

but everytime I submit an image to form nothing happens and I get code 500: internal server error, failed to load resource. I have placed breakpoints in my code but it never entered the File method. What am I doing wrong? htmlpage and script are located in wwwroot, controller is in Controllers folder.

Comment: If you check the Message of the exception raised which causes the 500 error it will tell you the exact cause and also the line of code which is raising that exception. You should check that.

Comment: All Google Chrome says is:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
Image/File:1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your action should take the image as a param:

```
// Don't use `File` here. You're hiding the base `File` method.
public IActionResult FileUpload(IFormFile file)
{
    // Always check content length
    if (file?.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        //work
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then, in your JS, the first param to `FormData.append` should be data name, not the name of the file. Since the action param is `file`, the name here should be `file` as well:

```
formData.append('file', files[0]);
```